# Change in "boldness" in 3d graphics in Mathematica 12.1.1 while rotating

Tags: graphics3d, notebooks, rendering

After updating mathematica from version 12.0 to 12.1.1,I noticed that 3D graphics change their boldness while being rotated.Is there a way to turn this off?It becomes annoying.Below are the attached pictures.First screenshot is taken before rotating with mouse.Notice the boldness.Second screenshot is taken while rotating with mouse.Notice the absence of boldness

[image: Before Rotating]

[image: While Rotating]

Comment: think the difference is a result of lower quality graphics being displayed during interaction  with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the "3DRenderingEngine" from Automatic to "Mesa" has fixed the problem.I believe the problem arises due to lack of support of Direct3D 11 on my old 2006 era machine.Quick look at the [wolfram](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) website shows that mathematica 12.1 uses Direct3D 11.